Behavior of itertools.count, zip and for loops
I have noticed this behavior:
import itertools as iter

truc = iter.count(0)
trac = ["a",'b','c','d','e']
for i in range(3):
    zap = [x for x,y in zip(truc,trac)]
    print(zap)

which outputs
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

I don't understand why the second list is not ```[5,6,7,8,9]```. And the same goes for the third list, why it does not start at 11 ?

zip() advances the iterators in left to right order - it calls next(truc), and then (possibly) next(trac).  But when truc yields 5, trac has reached its end, so the overall zip() process ends.  So the 5 gets wasted, it has no place in zip's output, and there's no way to stuff it back into the iterator it came from.

@jasonharper : I see, thank you ! Can you make your comment as a response so that I can mark it as an answer ?
